# BSD conjecture and L functions with zeroes of order g

Tags: analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, nt.number-theory

If the group of rational points of $E$, which is finitely generated by the Mordell-Weil Theorem, has $g$ generators of infinite order, then the Birch-Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture gives

$L_E(s)$ has a zero of order $g$ at $s=1$.

Assuming the BSD conjecture, is it possible to (and if so how) to construct such $L_E(s)$? Specifically, if we want $g=3$ or $4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by your question. Here are two remarks:

1. If you *assume* BSD, then to "construct" $L_E$ you just need to give the curve $E$. There are (many) elliptic curves /$\mathbb{Q}$ whose ranks have been computed, and are (say) equal to 3 or 4.
2. If one wants an example without assuming BSD, then you are in trouble - for given $E$, you can compute $L^{(n)}(s)$ to any desired degree of accuracy, but proving that it vanishes computationally is impossible.

However, two things help you. If the sign in the functional equation is -1, then you have that the order of vanishing is also odd. The Gross-Zagier formula can be used to check the vanishing of the first derivative. For example, this is used in the following paper to exhibit an elliptic curve $E$ whose $L_E$ provably vanishes to order 3.

On the Conjecture of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer for an Elliptic Curve of Rank 3 
Author(s): Joe P. Buhler, Benedict H. Gross, Don B. Zagier 
Source: Mathematics of Computation, Vol. 44, No. 170 (Apr., 1985), pp. 473-481

Comment: I'm in case 1.  I'm just curious where to find such curves E, and how to turn them in to $L_E(s)$.

Comment: In that case you're probably best off looking at Cremona's very detailed tables of elliptic curves of conductor < 130000:

http://www.warwick.ac.uk/staff/J.E.Cremona/ftp/data/

They include the $a_p$, which will allow you to write down the $L$-function by hand. 

For computing values of the L-function, T. Dokchitser has written a nice program that can do this given the input of the $a_p$ and a functional equation. It has been implemented in sage, and linked up with the elliptic curve functionality - cf. the example here:

http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/lfunctions/dokchitser.html

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: "you can compute L(n)(s) to any desired degree of accuracy, but proving that it vanishes computationally is impossible."

 Can't one discretize the L-value and check whether it is zero?

Comment: Sorry. That was sheer nonsense.